# Unable to increase qemu raw image file size

Tags: linux, filesystems, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I am trying to increase the size of the raw image from 2G by an extra 4G using the command

> $ qemu-img resize usb.img +4G

and it was successful.

> $ ls -l
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6405750784 Dec 22 13:58 usb.img

But inside the vm, the size still says 2G

> $ df -kh .
>
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/hda2       1.8G  1.6G   81M  96% /

I tried increasing the size of the partition inside the vm using

> $ resize2fs /dev/hda2
>
> resize2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
>
> The filesystem is already 1994752
> blocks long.  Nothing to do!

and

> $ resize2fs /dev/hda
>
> resize2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
>
> The filesystem is already 1994752 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Can anyone let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: First of all you are missing the point of StackOverflow - it's about *programming* and your question is not related to programming. It's offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gparted (on the host) to add the new disk to the existing partition.